# 2011 Moderator Elections - Town Hall Chat: 8pm UTC on the 30th

Tags: discussion, election

In connection with the moderator elections, we will be holding a Town Hall Chat session with the candidates.  This will be an opportunity for members of the community to pose questions to the candidates on the topic of moderation.  Participation is completely voluntary.  I am working with the candidates to find a time that allows the most participation.

**The Town Hall Chat will take place Sunday the 30th at 8pm UTC, or 3pm EST.**

[**(view in other timezones)**](http://www.timeanddate.com/worldclock/fixedtime.html?month=1&day=30&year=2011&hour=20&min=0&sec=0&p1=0)

[**(click here to join the chat room)**](https://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/505/town-hall-chat)

Here are the details so far:

- I have coordinated with the candidates and done the best I could with a best fit match.  <s>I would like to schedule this towards the beginning of the election phase.  This means that I am looking at the 29th-31st. As soon as I coordinate with the existing moderators and candidates to find a best fit based on availability, I will edit this post with details on the "when".</s>
- The Town Hall Chat will be a one-hour event using our [chat platform](https://chat.stackoverflow.com/?tab=all&sort=active).  You can register for the event [here](https://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/info/505/town-hall-chat?tab=schedule).
- The format will be an open discussion.  Users are encouraged to pose questions to the candidates regarding their thoughts on moderation.
- After the chat session, the transcript of the event will be [permanently linked here](https://chat.stackoverflow.com/transcript/505/2011/1/30/20-22).

Comment: That's a super great idea.  I'd like to hear what all of the other candidates have to say.  And I hope I'll get the chance to take part as well.

Comment: The SF chat with 7 candidates was a bit noisy (but still great), I wonder what it will be like with 30 candidates...

Comment: @Farseeker If it happens after the election phase has started it'll only be 10 candidates

Comment: @Michael - ah yes, forgot about that

Comment: Yes, my goal for each one is the first 48 hours of the final election phase.

Comment: WhoopWhoop!  Let's get excited!

Comment: Great! However due to the time choice, I'll only be able to participate for about half an hour. :(

Comment: I didn't get an email confirming what time it would be. Luckily @Justin sent me a tweet about it.

Comment: @George I only received notification because I favorited this question.

Comment: Me being thick?...but what's the bounty for?

Comment: @Kev, I'm guessing it's for Josh.  For creating the digest.  It will be a gift from Rebecca.

Comment: And it was much appreciated! Thanks Rebecca! :-D

Comment: @Kev, yes it was for Josh/TheRenamedException.  I know he put a lot of time and effort into creating the digest so I thought I'd give him a little gift.

Comment: So... ready for more town hall sessions?  Might be more interesting if we can have some during the primaries and the elections.

Comment: @AdamDavis, yup.  Was on my list for yesterday, so maybe it'll get done today. (:

Answer (score 8, accepted):

I want to extend a giant **thank you** to Rebecca for organizing all these Town Hall sessions. I think they were a huge success and I really hope everyone benefitted from them!

In order to make the Stack Overflow Town Hall easier to read, I have tried my best to produce a [digest version](https://chat.stackoverflow.com/transcript/message/289481#289481) containing only the questions and answers, sorted chronologically. If anyone has corrections, please let me know.

## Now get out and vote!

Comment: Thank you Josh for that! excellent job!

Comment: That's pretty neat, I didn't know you could do that.

Comment: @George: it took a lot of hard, manual work!

Comment: kudos. Hard work, but very worthwhile.