# Answering Town Hall Chat sessions that you could not attend

Tags: support, election, per-site-meta, town-hall-chat

Suppose you're a candidate in a moderator election and you could not attend the town hall chat nor post in the chat room until after the digest has been posted. What is the proper procedure to answer the questions? Is it ok to edit the chat transcripts to add your answers (in which case the THC digests should be CW)?

Comment: Why CW? Can users without edit privileges run for moderator?

Comment: @MatthewRead Yes, on most sites the rep requirement is only 300. It doesn't happen often, and I don't think there's been a case of a user with <2000 rep has been elected, but it's allowed by the rules, so there should not be a barrier.

Answer (score 11, accepted):

If you reply to the questions in the chat room after the digest is posted, your answers will be moved as soon as possible to the relevant digest answers. We (well, at least speaking for myself) typically monitor the Town Hall Chat room for the given site until the site's election is over, so anything new that's posted in there will be noticed*.

While there's certainly no punishment for doing so, we prefer that people don't edit the digest content directly as adding answers on behalf of candidates makes it easier for us to maintain a consistent format.

<sub>*Pinging me once you're done or through answering a question I asked during the Town Hall will typically get your answers added more quickly, since I otherwise don't always notice the new room activity right away.</sub>

Comment: Thanks. <shamefaced> I just noticed you did in fact write most of this in your digest header (how did I miss that last paragraph‽)</>, but I wanted to be sure not to do anything improper. The current procedure does make sense in that it constrains the candidates to the same medium. I hope it's not too much work to redo the digest, but man, 3am THC!

Comment: @Gilles No big deal for me at all, thanks for taking the time to provide answers! :)

Comment: Ok, I'm all done. Thanks for all the work!

Comment: Awesome, I'll update the digest in a few minutes.

Comment: When [I originally proposed Town Hall Digests](http://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/77831) I was strongly against CW because I felt it was important that the answers match the actual town hall chat, and having them be CW would defeat that purpose. Furthermore, the digests followed a very specific format, and allowing anyone to edit wouldn't enforce that format. Also, **answers should be provided in the chat**, even late, and then copied to the digest. Some people may only check the chat, and thus miss any edits to the digest.

Comment: @TheUnhandledException Yeah, that makes a lot of sense. I think we've been sticking with not making them CW for those reasons (though it's a bit tricky on MSO because of reps/auto-conversion due to the sheer number of questions).

Comment: Well Tim, that is easily solved. "SO THC Part 1", "SO THC Part 2", etc.